# What did Rasulullah (S.A.W) mean by Khudh and Kirman in this hadith about the mongol invasion?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

The Hadith is as follows

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet said, "The Hour will not be established till you fight
>   with the Khudh and the Kirman from among the non-Arabs. They will be
>   of red faces, flat noses and small eyes; their faces will look like
>   flat shields, and their shoes will be of hair."

Also [this](https://muflihun.com/bukhari/56/788) is the link.

Some say that the mongols are indicated by this hadith. They invaded Baghdad in 1258 AD. But here Rasulullah (S.A.W) mentions two names, Khudh and Kirman. Who are they?

If there's any problems in my question please do inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Khudh and the Kirman are tribes from the Turks, because in the following hadith preceding your mentioned hadith both descriptions exactly match eachother. Therefore I conclude the previous statement.

> **Narrated Abu Huraira, Book 61, Hadith 96**:
>
> *The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The Hour will not be established till you fight a nation wearing hairy shoes, and till you fight the Turks, who will have small eyes, red faces and flat noses; and their faces will be like flat shields. And you will find that the best people are those who hate responsibility of ruling most of all till they are chosen to be the rulers. And the people are of different natures: The best in the pre-lslamic period are the best in Islam. A time will come when any of you will love to see me rather than to have his family and property doubled."*

Source: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61

Comment: But the turks are arabs, the people in the hadith are non-arabs

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan : Not all Turks are Arabs. By that I mean a portion of the Turkish people. See the definition of Arab people [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Arabia) and [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Arabian).

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan : *Turkic people. Cf.  [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_peoples#History) and [this definition](http://teachmideast.org/articles/arab-middle-eastern-and-muslim-whats-the-difference/).

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer!! May Allah reward you!! I had this question for a long time in my mind and you solved it by the permission of Allah

Comment: Ameen, I'm glad I could help. Assaluma haleykum.

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan Turkjs and Arabs are two very different ethnicities!

Answer (score -2):

Well Kurd are Turkish people in origin and kimran are persian-mongols (mughals)